# Why would getFragmentManager result in an Incompatible Type error?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, fragment, android-support-library

[image]

I am making a simple to-do list App using FragmentManager. When I create an instance of `FragmentManager`, I am getting an error (as shown above).

Comment: what a title !!! seen after long time

Comment: use getSupportFragmentManager

Comment: `import android.app.FragmentManager` rather than the `.support.v4.` one...

Comment: Please, make sure that you had spent some time searching through the web, before posting a question here!

Comment: The -9 votes were almost certainly because of the title that was originally used here. Please always use useful and descriptive titles when asking a technical question, on any site on the internet. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`getFragmentManagaer()` returns object of [android.app.FragmentManager.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager()) Use `getSupportFragmentManager()` it returns   [android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportFragmentManager())

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong type of FragmentManager (one is android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager and the other is android.app.FragmentManager.) Try getSupportFragmentManager().

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of fragment manager in android one is app.FragmentManager and the other one in v4.app.FragmentManager. and here you are using v4 support fragment.

So to get the instance of fragment manager, you have to write

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

OR If you want to use

```
 FragmentManager fm = getSupportManager();
```

Then remove the import of

```
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
```

And import

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
```